# Create new database from chunk reader in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I'm working with a massive excel file (14GB) that I need to clean so only the information I need is left. I made the file into Chunks so my computer would stop crashing, but now need to create a new database that shows only the data for the city I am looking for.

I have made it to print(chunk)

```
for chunk in reader:
    print(chunk)
```

am unsure how to continue, I tried

```
df = reader
df = reader[reader.SitusCity == Miami]
```

But get this error code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-d4c11720d1c5> in <module>()
----> 1 df = reader[reader.SitusCity == Miami]

AttributeError: 'TextFileReader' object has no attribute 'SitusCity'
```

Help!!!

Comment: Not sure why you made literally everything a snippet, but that's for HTML and JS, not Python and error stacks

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
chunk in reader:
    chunk.ix[chunk.SitusCity == 'Miami'].to_excel('output.xlsx', mode='a')
```